# Bulk-deleting inbox mails managed by POSTFIX

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, postfix, inbox

Had an issue several hours ago with a client mail account, which got compromised.
As a result, he had hundreds of thousands of spam queued in postfix, which lead to several issues.
Everything's fixed and security's tied up, apart from one "small" issue: the client now has close to 100k of returned spam mails in his inbox.
And obviously, I'm looking for a bulk operation with some filtering as everything's not junk.
PF runs on Ubuntu server v10.x, with maildir.

I tried this command on a backed-up folder containing the same files:

```
grep -l -r 'Undelivered' | xargs rm
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything apart from running.

Can this come from the fact that all the "mails" are stored inside files named this way:

> 1395063807.V902Ib2081dM533672.ip.ip.ip:2,

Comment: What is your mailbox type? `mbox`, `maildir` or other? What `pop/imap` server do you use?

Comment: Using maildir, but the issue's been fixed: was just using an older version of grep that requires a directory to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of `grep`, this might wait forever because you don't have given a file (or directory) name as argument; `grep`'s behavior to use the current working directory when `-r` is specified is a rather new feature.  Thus if your version is an older one, this your call might wait forever for input on `stdin`.  Just add `.` as last argument to `grep` to avoid this case.

To avoid issues with file names (which shouldn't be a problem in this case), it would be safest to call

```
grep -Zl -r 'Undelivered' . | xargs -0 rm --
```

This way, `grep` outputs the matching file names zero-byte (`'\0'`) separated, which avoids trouble with spaces and alike in file names.   `--` tells `rm` to not treat the following arguments as options, i.e. if a file name starts with a `-` it doesn't break.

To see whether this command does anything at all, you could add the `-v` option to `rm`, so you could see whether `rm` does actually remove anything (in front of `--`, of course).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I kinda feel dumb for forgetting that dot, as it was indeed what caused the hang-up.

Comment: I had to edit this answer to get it, too, thus don't feel bad. ;)  I'm using Gentoo/testing thus my `grep` supports the ommited `.`, too, and I regularly fall over this on other machines.